# django_libsass failed to install in openshift

Tags: django, openshift, libsass

django_libsass package is failed to install in openshift and the error is given below.Any solution for this ?

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Not sure what could be the problem, but a more verbose traceback would be essential for anyone to help you, I think.

Comment: I am also getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 36: ordinal not in range(128)` when trying to install `libsass` or `django-libsass`.